# What is the mincore syscall used for in userland applications?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

What is Linux' `mincore(2)` useful for in userland applications? Why is it exposed to non-privileged users?

I can imagine some databases taking advantage of knowing which pages are cached but what are some other examples?

Comment: Seems like it could be used in performance management code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is Linux `mincore(2)` useful for in userland applications?

I'd say that's most probably opinion based. Profiling, statistics, performance evaluation and stuff like that comes to mind. Other than that, I cannot think of other realistic legitimate use cases.

Here are some examples of programs I found that use `mincore` (as you can see, all profiling/statistics related):

- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/fincore.1.html
- https://github.com/fornwall/pagecache
- https://github.com/bwaldvogel/mongocachestat
- https://github.com/touzaniMarouane/BlackLab

> Why is it exposed to non-privileged users?

This would have actually been a good question around [one year ago](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=574823bfab82d9d8fa47f422778043fbb4b4f50e), when the syscall's semantics weren't clearly defined, and the existence of such a syscall was rather questionable. Prior to kernel version 4.14.2 `mincore` could in fact have been abused to leak uninitialized kernel memory from user space (see [CVE-2017-16994](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2017-16994) and the relative [Project Zero bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/project-zero/issues/detail?id=1431)).

Since then the syscall has been patched and its semantics updated. The only thing that a process can do by invoking it is to query information about its virtual memory map. Nothing harmful really, just self-inspection, hence the availability to unprivileged processes. There's no real reason to make it a privileged syscall, which if done could be also considered an API breakage.